# Create a conditional list using vba and named ranges

Tags: vba, list, conditional-statements

The formula used to create dynamic lists (using named ranges `MDES`,`M01DES`,...) does not work:

```
Range("Tableau1[Code DES d''affectation]").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
         .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "=si(B2=""M"",MDES,si(B2=""M01"",M01DES,si(B2=""P"",PDES,si(B2=""P01"",P01DES,si(B2=""P02"",P02DES,si(B2=""M01"",M01DES,si(B2=""O01"",O01DES)))))))"
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem

Thank you

Comment: Does `si(...)` means `if(...)`? Or is this custom function?

Comment: Yes. I also tried with the english "=if(B2=""M"",MDES,if(B2=""M01"",M01DES;""""))"

Comment: As to me, the last `if()` does not contain `else` part... So, you have to replace: `si(B2=""M01"",M01DES,si(B2=""O01"",O01DES))` with `si(B2=""M01"",M01DES,O01DES)`. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: No it does not work : it does not show me the list but the formula

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is this

Range("Tableau1[Code DES d''affectation]").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=SI(B2=""P02"";NB.SI(P02DES;W2)=0;si(B2=""O01"";NB.SI(O01DES;W2)=0;SI(B2=""P01"";NB.SI(P01DES;W2)=0;si(B2=""P"";NB.SI(PDES;W2)=0;si(B2=""M"";NB.SI(MDES;W2)=0;SI(B2=""M01"";NB.SI(M01DES;W2)=0;SI(B2=""O"";NB.SI(ODES;W2)=0)))))))"